Xcode 16 crash immediately after using console filters
After updating Xcode to version 16, I have an issue using the console filter.
Basically settings filter or just passing with the mouse upon the filter Xcode crashing.
I'm unable to using filter.
Did anyone have the same issue or have found a solution?
Thanks
Using console filter in order to discriminate logs is not working with Xcode 16, I'm aspecting to using filter log.

Resolved Issues
Fixed crashes and other anomalies that could occur in the String Catalog editor when multiple editor tabs are open to the same file with different sort or filter criteria. (FB14665353) (136257968)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-16_2-release-notes
It seems Xcode 16.2 will solve the problem

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
